# rpy2: Reading a file to a Float Vector

Tags: r, python-3.x, rpy2

I have a simple file:

`1
2
4
5
...`

In R I can read the file to the vector:

`data = read.table (file_name, header = FALSE)`

I want to do something similar with `rpy2`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro

in_data = ro.FloatVector()
in_data.from_csvfile (path = in_file, header = False)
```

But I have an error at the line `in_data = ro.FloatVector()`. The error is `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'`

I don't know what type of `obj` I should pass into the function.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates it`FloatVector` requires a parameter (see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/vector.html#rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector).

There is also a short introduction to creating R vectors in the documentation: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/introduction.html#creating-rpy2-vectors